# Смена координат только "parent DIV" без подобъектов

Tags: javascript, css, html

Добрый день!

Есть Div, в котором внутри несколько других Div, с атрибутами position:absolute. Размеры и координаты всех фиксированны и известны. Нужно передвинуть родительский DIV так, чтоб все внутренние DIV'ы визуально на экране в целом выглядели на прежнем месте.

Всё былоб просто, но координаты внутренних подобъектов тоже должны измениться на расстояние перемещения родительского объекта (эта цифра известна, допустим 20px).

Пробовал менять CSS родительского и в цикле менять координаты каждого внутреннего DIV, но так не подходит - всёравно на глаз заметно дёргание при перемещении. Хотелось бы одним движением переместить родительский объект, а внутренние объекты чтоб подстроились сами автоматически и мгновенно. Как такое сделать? Важна скорость.

Код:

```
<div style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:15px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:55px;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понятна ситуация. Нужно визуально сохранить положения дочерних дивов относительно родительского дива или относительно картины в целом? Какое позиционирование у родительского дива? Приведите ваш код.

Comment: Да, "Нужно визуально сохранить положения дочерних дивов относительно родительского дива". У родительского объекта сейчас позиционирование тоже абсолютное. Пример кода добавлю в главный пост

Comment: В таком случае дочерние абсолютные элементы должны итак следовать за родителем т.к. позиционируются относительно него.

Comment: Они следуют, а нужно именно сделать вид, что они остались на старом месте как независимые, т.е. не двигались

Comment: Дак что нужно то:  "Да, "Нужно визуально сохранить положения дочерних дивов относительно родительского дива"."  Или наоборот от общей картины

Comment: Простите :) на экране в целом они должны остаться на старом месте

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если у тебя через цикл выходит дергание (что в общем-то странно, м.б. ты где-то в js ошибся - но ты его здесь не привел, так что ладно) - почему бы тебе не пойти на хитрость и не сделать так:

```
<div id="back" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;"></div>
<div id="box" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;">
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:15px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:55px;"></div>
</div>
```

`#box` сделать без визуального оформлеия, которое перенести на `#back` (задав ему размеры, равные `#box` и z-index на единицу меньше. Таким образом, когда потребуется, ты сможешь двигать этот самый `#back` вместо `#box` - визуально это будет выглядить так, словно ты двигаешь этот самый Div оставляя дочерние элементы на месте.
Можно поместить `#back` и в сам `#box`, задав ему минимальный z-index если хочешь, чтобы до какого-то времени они двигались синхронно

```
<div id="box" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;">
<div id="back" style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:15px;"></div>
    <div style="position:absolute; top:10px; left:55px;"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.parent {top:50px; left:100px;}
.parent .child1 {top:10px; left:15px;}

.parent.move {top:70px; left:120px;}
.parent.move .child1 {top:-10px; left:-5px;}
```

Comment: Можно подробней? Неочень понятно как этим воспользоваться, при нажатии кнопки например